# Count the number of symbols in a 'new symbology' renderer from pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qt

Background : I create a lot of symbology using 'saturation' ramps - for want of a better term, e.g. where the hue and value of each symbol stays the same, but the saturation changes. I couldn't figure out how to do this easily in qgis (EDIT: see comment - its easy when you know how), and each time I classify items, the colours reset to a colour ramp rather than a saturation ramp.

I figured this should be relatively easy to do using pyqgis, which it turns out has been, using this code (built for 5 symbols):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor              # import this namespace as I want to refer to QColor later
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
i = 0                                       # used to increment the saturation value
for sym in layer.rendererV2.symbols():      # loop through each symbol in the layer using 'new symbology'
    i += 50                                 
    sym.setColor(QColor.fromHsv(40,i,255))
```

Problem: . The above code works fine, but is not dynamic, in that I've set it up to increase the saturation by 50 each time (giving 5 graduations between 0 and 255). I want to set the saturation to graduate dynamically based on the total number of symbols.

The mathematics of this are pretty straight-forward, but I'm not able to get the count from the symbols() method. I've tried:

```
>>> rendererV2.symbols().count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

... which as you can see returns an error (although the QT documentation seems to list count() as a method of a QList<> object).

I've tried:

```
>>> rendererV2.symbols().count(QgsSymbol)
0
```

... which as you can see returns 0, which isn't true. There are 5 items in the list.

I'm sure I must be doing something daft, but being new to python, pyqgis and qt, it is beyond my ability to see what at present.

Help?

Comment: This would also make a good feature request.

Comment: I've just realised that I can actually achieve a 'saturation ramp' using QGIS color ramp, and setting the second colour to white! Exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `len()`

```
 len(layer.rendererV2().symbols())
```

Like so:

```
 >>> len(layer.rendererV2().symbols())
 1
```

**EDIT**: Count doesn't work because you are getting back a native Python list not a QList and the Python count method is different.  There are no QList binding in PyQt because they are auto converted to list.

```
>>> type(layer.rendererV2().symbols()) is list
True
```

Count in Python:

```
>>> mylist = [1,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
>>> mylist.count(5)
2
```

Counts the number of 5s in the list.

Comment: Great, thanks. Obvious when you know how. I'm interested as to why the count() on the QList doesn't work still however? Any insight?

Comment: See my edit to the answer.